# lit-element property passing to another function/class

Tags: javascript, class, properties, lit-element

I am currently learning how to use lit-elements, and I am also fairly new with web development. I am trying to make a Bluetooth custom element that changes a button text and color depending on if the bluetooth device is connected or not.

In my lit-element I create another class called BTLE, where all the bluetooth is handled.
But I have no idea how to pass a lit-element property to this BTLE class.
I want my button to get re-rendered when the BTLE class notices a connect or disconnect.
If I pass a property through the BTLE class via the constructor and I change the property the button is not re-rendered. If I change the property inside the lit-element class it gets re-rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to solve this with LitElement is to make the BTLE object emit events when its state changes, and for other objects (like custom elements) that care about its state to listen for those events.

The easiest way to do that in a web app is to make the BTLE class extend [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), which will give it `addEventListener`, `dispatchEvent`, etc. methods. Then, instead of passing callback functions to the BTLE constructor, your custom element will call `addEventListener` on it to start listening. When the BTLE object's status changes, instead of calling `this.callbackFunction(...)` it will call `this.dispatchEvent(new Event('state-change'))` (for example).

To accomplish this, your custom element will need to define a custom getter and setter so it knows when its `bluetoothGatt` property changes, because it will need to call `addEventListener` on the new BTLE. This is the most complex part, so I strongly recommend reading the section ["Configure property accessors"](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#accessors-custom) in the LitElement docs.

In the below snippet you can see a working example of how this might look in practice:

```js
const { LitElement, html } = litElement;

const BluetoothGattState = { Disconnected: 0, Connected: 1 };

// A simple app to test our custom element
class MyApp extends LitElement {
  render() {
    // Pass the BTLE object to `<bt-indicator>` as a property
    return html`
      <bt-indicator .bluetoothGatt=${new BTLE()}></bt-indicator>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-app', MyApp);

// Our <bt-indicator> custom element
class BtIndicator extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      bluetoothGatt: { type: Object },
      btState: { type: Number },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bluetoothGatt = null;
    this._handleBtGattStateChange = this._handleBtGattStateChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return html`Bluetooth status: ${
      this.btState === BluetoothGattState.Connected ? '✅' : ''
    }`;
  }

  // A custom setter that calls addEventListener whenever the bluetoothGatt
  // property changes
  set bluetoothGatt(obj) {
    const oldObj = this._bluetoothGatt;

    if (oldObj) {
      // Remove event listener from old BTLE
      oldObj.removeEventListener('state-change', this._handleBtGattStateChange);
    }

    if (obj) {
      this._bluetoothGatt = obj;
      this.btState = obj.state;
      // Add event listener to new BTLE
      obj.addEventListener('state-change', this._handleBtGattStateChange);
    } else {
      this._bluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    // Tell LitElement the property changed so it can re-render
    this.requestUpdate('bluetoothGatt', oldObj);
  }
  
  get bluetoothGatt() {
    return this._bluetoothGatt;
  }
  
  _handleBtGattStateChange(evt) {
    // update this.btState when the BTLE's stage changes
    this.btState = evt.target.state;
  }
}
customElements.define('bt-indicator', BtIndicator);


// BTLE as a simple EventTarget -- connects/disconnects every 1000ms and
// dispatches 'state-change'
class BTLE extends EventTarget {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.setState(BluetoothGattState.Disconnected);
    
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(this.state === BluetoothGattState.Disconnected ? BluetoothGattState.Connected : BluetoothGattState.Disconnected);
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  setState(val) {
    this.state = val;
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('state-change'));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lit-element@2.2.1"></script>

<my-app><my-app>
```

Comment: wow, and i though lit-elements were easy ;)  Thanks for the code it really helped a lot!. I didn't think about using an event. The only thing is that I cannot make a copy of the BTLE class because it is a very big class with also hardware states inside. So I removed the copying from old to new in the set function and put a requestupdate(1,0) inside _handleBtGattStateChange(evt). So it always updates when the statechange is called. And  it still seems to works!

Comment: Non-primitive values in JavaScript are passed by reference. Assigning an object to a variable or property does not make a copy of the object. It sets the variable or property to a reference to the object.

Comment: Oke, that saves a lot of processor power. But still it compares the old object with the new object. So there must be 2 instances of the BTLE class in memory. Is at every new eventDispatch a new class instance  made ?

Comment: If you’re changing the `bluetoothGatt` property from one instance of BTLE to another one then yes, there are two instance in memory. That’s going to be the case regardless of the code you put in the setter, though. Re: your second question, if you’re asking if a new instance of Event is created every time `new Event` is called, the answer is yes.

Comment: Oke thanks Jordan, it is getting a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I made a callback function inside my litelement class as a workaround. So the bluetooth class is created like this :

```
this.bluetoothGatt = new BTLEclass(this.bluetoothDevice, this, this.bluetoothCallback);
```

and then in the bluetooth class the constructor looks like :

```
constructor(bluetoothDevice: any, callingClass: any, callbackfunction: any) {
        this.bluetoothDevice = bluetoothDevice;
        this.state = BluetoothGattState.Disconnected;
        this.callback  = callingClass;
        this.callbackfunction = callbackfunction;
    }
```

the callback is called like this :

```
this.callbackfunction.call(this.callback,this.connectionStr);
```

And the callback inside litelement  :

```
bluetoothCallback(constr:string)
  {
     this.connectedStr = constr;
  }
```

property inside litelement:

```
 @property() connectedStr: string = 'connect';
```

It works but it is very ugly!
Is there a way I can make the BTLE class a friend of litelement class (like in C++) so I can change it inside the BTLE class directly (and the button gets re-renderd)

Or is there a better way to do this in javascript/litelement/webcomponents ?
should I use MobX for something like this ?